# How to properly use matplotlib's set_xticks?

Tags: matplotlib

I have the following code for making a plot

```
year   = "2008"
months = [
    "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
    "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
]

fig = plt.figure()
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(111)

indices = range(1,len(months)+1)

# daily_sf_samples_dic and daily_normal_samples_dic are dictionary with day_number between '000' and 
# '365' as keys. The values for these dictionaries are number of samples for each day in either 
# category
all_daily_samples = [
    list(daily_sf_samples_dic.values()),
    list(daily_normal_samples_dic.values())
]

colors = ['m', 'g']
labels = ['Normal', 'SF']

# we modify the number of bins to plot daily, monthly, yearly. Here 12 bins to imply monthly
ax0.hist(all_daily_samples,12,histtype='bar',color = colors, label = labels)

ax0.set_ylabel('Number of Samples')
ax0.set_xlabel('Month')
ax0.set_xticks(indices) # Is something wrong here???
ax0.set_xticklabels(months)
ax0.set_title('Monthly Ionogram count Y' + year)
ax0.legend(loc='best')

plt.show()
```

When I make the plot the xticks don't show up appropriately. What I get is this:

[image]

The xlabels and the xticks are all bunched together and do not show in the appropriate places at all.

What might I be doing wrong?
I have tried:

1. Use set_xticklabels without set_xticks-->Only some of the months are shown and in arbitrary positions

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is a discrepancy between the bin width and the x-locations you're supplying for the labels.

When `matplotlib` computes a histogram, it takes the data you feed into it and starts counting it into bins. In this case, you've told `matplotlib` that you want your data counted into 12 bins. However, you have not told it to use specific bin edges, so `matplotlib` assumes you want bins wide enough to encapsulate all of your data. If your data ranges from, say, 0 to 1200 inclusive, then `matplotlib` determines that you implicitly want 12 bins of width 100 each. Any values between 0 and 100 are counted in one bin, any between 100 and 200 in the next, and so on. However, your x-axis still ranges from 0 to 1200. At this point, you've then told the interpreter that you want to have 12 x-ticks positioned at locations  `x = range(1, 13)` and to place new labels over those ticks. For an x-axis ranging from 0 to 1200, x-ticks located at 1 to 12 stack up on top of each other, as you've seen.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

months = [
    "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
    "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
]

data   = np.abs(np.random.normal(scale = 60, size = 10000)) ** 1.2
n_bins = len(months)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(data, n_bins)

# Ticks matching the number, but not the position, of bins.
ticks  = np.arange(1, len(months) + 1)
labels = months

ax.set_xticks(ticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)

plt.show()
```

[image: A histogram with stacked x-axis labels.]

The x-ticks you've given **would** work if the bins were all of width 1. We could, of course, specify that we want bins of width 1, but 12 bins of width 1 would limit the data counted by our histogram to values between 0 and 12. If our data goes all the way up to 1200, we're dropping a lot of values. Since we don't want to omit data, we can instead resolve to place the labels at their correct locations by calculating the centers of the bins and using those to place the x-ticks.

A useful behavior of `matplotlib` is that `ax.hist` [returns three values](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html), the second of which is the edges of the bins. The number of edges is 1 greater than the number of bins you provided as an argument to the `ax.hist` function. By taking the difference between consecutive bin edges, we get the separation between them. We can then add half of these differences to the bin edges themselves, dropping the last edge to avoid an off-by-one error, to get the bin centers. Using these bin centers as the locations for our new set of x-ticks gives the labels the correct locations.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

months = [
    "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
    "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
]

data   = np.abs(np.random.normal(scale = 60, size = 10000)) ** 1.2
n_bins = len(months)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
_, edges, _ = ax.hist(data, n_bins)

# Ticks placed at the center of the bins.
ticks  = edges[:-1] + np.diff(edges) / 2
labels = months

ax.set_xticks(ticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)

plt.show()
```

[image: A histogram with centered x-axis labels.]

This method still works even if you have multiple datasets in the same histogram.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

months = [
    "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
    "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
]

data1  = np.abs(np.random.normal(scale = 60, size = 10000)) ** 1.1
data2  = np.abs(np.random.normal(scale = 60, size = 10000)) ** 1.2
n_bins = len(months)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
_, bins, _ = ax.hist([data1, data2], n_bins)

ticks  = bins[:-1] + np.diff(bins) / 2
labels = months

ax.set_xticks(ticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)

plt.show()
```

[image: A histogram with two datasets with shared centered x-labels.]